# Trace of an induced representation on $G(\mathbb A)$

Tags: representation-theory, reductive-groups, langlands-program

Let $G = \operatorname{GL}_2$, with center $Z$, diagonal matrices $T$, and upper triangular unipotents $N$.  Let $K$ be the standard maximal compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb A) = G(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$.  For a character $\omega$ of $\mathbb A^{\ast}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}$, trivial on $(0,\infty)$, define a character $\omega_s$ of $N(\mathbb A)Z(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb Q)T(\mathbb R)^0$ by

$$\omega_s( n \begin{pmatrix} a \alpha u & x\\ & a \beta v \end{pmatrix}) = \omega(a)|\frac{u}{v}|^{s} \tag{$x \in \mathbb A, a \in \mathbb A^{\ast}, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb Q^{\ast}, u,v \in (0,\infty)$}$$

If we let $H(s) = \operatorname{Ind}_{N(\mathbb A)Z(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb Q)T(\mathbb R)^0}^{G(\mathbb A)} \omega_s$ (normalized Mackey induction), then this is a Hilbert space for $s \in i\mathbb R$, and the representation $\pi_s$ of $G(\mathbb A)$ by right translation is unitary.

If $\varphi$ is a smooth function on $G(\mathbb A)$, compactly supported modulo $Z(\mathbb A)$, and satisfies $\varphi(zg) = \omega(z)^{-1} \varphi(g)$, we can define a bounded linear operator $R(\varphi)$ on $H(s)$ by

$$R(\varphi)f(x) = \int\limits_{Z(\mathbb A) \backslash G(\mathbb A)} \varphi(y)f(xy)dy.$$

This operator should be a Hilbert-Schmidt operator of trace class, and I want to compute its trace.  In the Corvallis article *Forms of GL(2) from the analytic point of view*,  the trace computation is given on page 239.

This computation shows up in integrating the truncated continuous kernel in $L^2_{\textrm{cont}}(Z(\mathbb A)G(\mathbb A)\backslash G(\mathbb A),\omega)$.  What I get here should cancel out with a term that is picked up in the truncated kernel on all of $L^2(Z(\mathbb A)G(\mathbb A)\backslash G(\mathbb A),\omega)$.

[image]

I haven't been able to make this formula come out.  I'm guessing the process is to unwind the integral $R(\varphi)$ over, say, $N(\mathbb A)Z(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb Q)T(\mathbb R)^0$, and show that $R(\varphi)$ is like an integral operator, its trace being given by an integral over a diagonal.  I haven't yet been able to obtain a quotient of $G(\mathbb A)$ whose integration is given by the above.  My guess is something like $Z(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb A^{\ast 1}) \backslash G(\mathbb A)$, since

$$T(\mathbb A)/T(\mathbb A^{\ast 1})Z(\mathbb A) \cong \mathbb Q^{\ast} \times (0,\infty)$$

and from $G(\mathbb A) = T(\mathbb A)N(\mathbb A)K$ we should have an Iwasawa decomposition-like decomposition

$$\int\limits_{Z(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb A^{\ast 1}) \backslash G(\mathbb A)} = \int\limits_{T(\mathbb A)/T(\mathbb A^{\ast 1})Z(\mathbb A)} \space \space \int\limits_{N(\mathbb A)} \int\limits_K$$

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it.  Let $H = N(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb R)^0 T(\mathbb Q)Z(\mathbb A)$.  We can write

$$R(\varphi)f(x) = \int\limits_{Z(\mathbb A)\backslash G(\mathbb A)} \varphi(x^{-1}y) f(y)dy = \int\limits_{H \backslash G(\mathbb A)} \space \int\limits_{Z(\mathbb A) \backslash H} \varphi(x^{-1}hy) f(hy)dhdy $$

$$ = \int\limits_{H \backslash G(\mathbb A)} \space K(x,y) f(y)dy$$

where $K(x,y) = \int\limits_{Z(\mathbb A) \backslash H} \varphi(x^{-1}hy)\omega_s(y)dy$.  For general reasons,

$$\operatorname{Tr} R(\varphi) = \int\limits_{H\backslash G(\mathbb A)} K(x,x)dx.$$

By some Iwasawa decomposition argument (see e.g. page 221 of the article), integration over $H \backslash G(\mathbb A)$ satisfies

$$\int\limits_{H \backslash G(\mathbb A)} K(x,x)dx = \int\limits_K \int\limits_{\mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}} K( \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k, \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k)d^{\ast}adk.$$

Note that

$$K( \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k, \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k) = \int\limits_{Z(\mathbb A) \backslash H} \varphi\Bigg[k^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}h \begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}k\Bigg] \omega_s(h) dh$$

Also, $Z(\mathbb A) \backslash H$ is the product of $N(\mathbb A)$ with $\Big(Z(\mathbb A) \cap \big(T(\mathbb R)^0 T(\mathbb Q)\big) \Big) \backslash T(\mathbb R)^0 T(\mathbb Q)\big] \cong \mathbb Q^{\ast} \times (0,\infty)$.  Therefore, the trace is

$$\int\limits_K \int\limits_{\mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}}\int\limits_{N(\mathbb A)} \sum\limits_{\alpha \in \mathbb Q^{\ast}} \int_0^{\infty} \phi\Bigg[k^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} t \alpha \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} n\begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} k\Bigg]\omega_s\begin{pmatrix} t \alpha \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} dt  dn d^{\ast}a dk.$$

We get a cancelation of $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $a \in \mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}$, so the integral is independent of that variable.  Also, the character $\omega_s$ evaluates to $|t|^{s+1/2}$.  So, the trace is now

$$\operatorname{vol}(\mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}) \int\limits_K  \int\limits_{N(\mathbb A)}\sum\limits_{\alpha \in \mathbb Q^{\ast}} \int_0^{\infty} \phi\Bigg[k^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} t \alpha \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}n k\Bigg]|t|^{s+1/2} dt dn  dk$$
which is exactly the required formula.